# Convert DateTime from UTC to a user provided time zone with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone

Say, if I have a database column that holds date/time in UTC time zone, I can read them into DateTime object in my ASP.NET web app written with C#. How do I convert them to a user provided time zone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes that `time` has a `Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc`

You could use [`ConvertTimeFromUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx):

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, userTimeZone);
```

Or [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx):

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(time, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, userTimeZone);
```

You will probably want to check out the MSDN article on [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx) for the ins and outs of the method.

It's probably worth reading all about [converting between time zones on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx) as well. It's more complex than you might think.

Comment: Thanks alot! One follow-up question. If I want to store a list of time zones for a user to select, what property of TimeZoneInfo is better to store in a DropDownCtrl value?

Comment: Seems like the time zone's Id would be a reasonable property

Comment: My only concern about it is that ID is a string, something like "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)" and not just a number. I'm somewhat concerned about localization?

Comment: Ah okay. In that case, `BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours` might work.

Answer (score 3):

To  get Time Zones list  in a system  you can use TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() .It will 
give you a list of all available TimeZones for your system.

```
      List<TimeZoneInfo>  lstTZI = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToList();
```

Because it is ReadOnlyCollection .Now You can bind this source with your DropDownCntrl .

Comment: Nice addition. Thanks. Just curious, is there any way to get a time zone selected in a user's web browser?

Comment: GetCurrent Time Zone using TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone and find it using it's standard name in list lstTZI .