# DateTime conversions using NodaTime on ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor website. How to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor, nodatime

I have the Date/Time stored in the database on the London's time zone (not UTC).
What I need is to retrieve this Date/Time, convert it to UTC and display considering the user's time zone (which they define when registering to the site - ie: en-GB, en-US, etc).

My first question is more related to the MVC structure, as I'm totally new to this (am a WebForms developer) - Where should I put this conversion code/class/helper? Model? ViewModel?

The second question is the conversion itself - I've played around with the NodaTime test project but can't find a proper way to do this conversion.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon Skeet may need to correct me, as I'm assuming this is correct in [nodatime](/questions/tagged/nodatime):

```cs
// Timezone data provider (inject with DI)
IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;

// London Timezone (can keep this as a singleton, since it'll be used often)
var londonTimeZone = timeZoneProvider["Europe/London"];

// Get your date/time from the database and map it as being local to London timezone
var yourDateFromDb = new DateTime(2013, 01, 23, 21, 00, 00); // This is what you'll get back from your database (although you may get back a DateTimeOffset)
ZoneLocalMapping zonedDbDateTime = londonTimeZone.AtLeniently(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(yourDateFromDb)); <-- This is your date time with the correct offset (taking into account DST etc.)

// Map the London zoned date/time to the users local date/time
var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/Paris"; // <-- Store this value in users profile/db
var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];
var usersZonedDateTime = zonedDbDateTime.WithZone(usersTimezone);

Assert.That(usersZonedDateTime.Hour == 22);
```

You should probably be aware that during timezone transitions (autumn clock change), you may get 2 possible dates for the zonedDbDateTime.  The code here just gets the first or earliest date/time.

Edit: Updated code snippet with changes suggested by Jon Skeet

Comment: I'd use `londonTimeZone.AtLeniently` rather than the map, but otherwise that's right. It may be worth noting that `en-GB` (etc) aren't normal time zone identifiers.

Comment: Also, it might be worth changing `usersLocalDateTime` to `usersZonedDateTime` as it *is* a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @JonSkeet good point regarding the locale. I should've put my question on a better way. I'll do this conversion based on the user's date/time settings (time zone) - using a javascript plugin which will return me the time zone id. The locale saved on the user's profile will be used just to format the result.

Comment: Thanks both for the answer. Will try it now.

Comment: Just one more thing. I'll be returning the result as DateTime. What's the best way to convert from ZonedDateTime to DateTime? Thanks!

Comment: @MelanciaUK: `ZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc` or `ZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified` depending on which Kind you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can write some extension method like this :

```
public static DateTime ConvertToUtc(this DateTime d)
{
    //do conversin and return it
}
```

and you will be able to call it like @Model.MyDate.ConvertToUtc() from any view you wish as long as you have the namespace of the ConvertToUtc inclucded on the top of page. 
and to do the conversion see this pages

[Convert DateTime from UTC to a user provided time zone with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623472/convert-datetime-from-utc-to-a-user-provided-time-zone-with-c-sharp)

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=593

[How to work with time zones in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832986/how-to-work-with-timezone-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I'm currently using NodaTime on this project.