# NodaTime conversions (Part 2). How to?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, nodatime

**Following my first post:**

[DateTime conversions using NodaTime on ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor website. How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164994/datetime-conversions-using-nodatime-on-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-website-how-to)

I'm struggling to find an easy way to convert date/time between local and UTC (both ways), using NodaTime.

**The current picture is:**

- I have the date/time saved as UTC in the database.
- When displaying it to the user, I should consider the local time zone and convert it accordingly.
- When the user provides date/time as a filter, I need to convert it back to UTC before sending to the SQL query.

**What I have so far:**

Extension to convert from UTC to local (this part is working fine):

```
    public static DateTime UTCtoLocal(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;

        var utcTimeZone = timeZoneProvider["UTC"];
        var dateTimeFromDb = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond);

        var zonedDbDateTime = utcTimeZone.AtLeniently(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimeFromDb));

        var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/London"; //just an example
        var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];

        var usersZonedDateTime = zonedDbDateTime.WithZone(usersTimezone);

        return usersZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
    }
```

Extension to convert from local back to UTC (this part is the problem):

```
    public static DateTime LocaltoUTC(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
        var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/London";
        var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];

        var dateTimeFromDb = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond);
        var zonedDbDateTime = usersTimezone.AtLeniently(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTimeFromDb));

        var utcTimezoneId = "UTC";
        var utcTimezone = timeZoneProvider[utcTimezoneId];

        var utcZonedDateTime = zonedDbDateTime.WithZone(utcTimezone);

        return utcZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your UTCToLocal looks like it's doing more work than it needs to, to be honest.

It should just be:

```
// Note: the DateTime here must have a "Kind" of Utc.
public static DateTime UTCtoLocal(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);
    IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
    var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/London"; //just an example
    var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];
    var usersZonedDateTime = instant.InZone(usersTimezone);
    return usersZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
}
```

Similarly your LocalToUTC should be along these lines:

```
// The DateTime here should have a "Kind" of Unspecified
public static DateTime LocaltoUTC(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);

    IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
    var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/London";
    var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];

    var zonedDbDateTime = usersTimezone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
    return zonedDbDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
}
```

You don't need to convert it to a different time zone: `ZonedDateTime` knows what the instant is, and `ToDateTimeUtc` will do the right thing. Note that there's no real `dateTimeFromDb` here, because if you're converting from an unspecified `DateTime`, that's presumably from the user...

Comment: Thanks again, @Jon. Will try this one out. Keep up with the good work on NodaTime.

Comment: what is the use of LocaltoUTC, shouldn't DateTime.ToUniversalTime() work just fine? thanks

Comment: @pajics: No, because that will always use the system time zone - the OP wants to use the user's time zone.

Comment: When converting from a LocalDateTime to Utc, does NodaTime take into account future timezone daylight savings? Ex: You convert LocalDateTime of July 4, 2020 at 4:00PM EST to Utc, but the conversion is done in February, so at the time of the conversion EST offset is -5, but at the time of the date being converted, EST offset is -4.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: The date on which you do the conversion is completely irrelevant. The date being converted is all that's relevant.

Comment: Correction: not AtLieniently, I meant to make sure ToDateTimeUtc was taking account of what the DLS would be at the time specified by LocalDateTime/DateTimeZone.